# Trying to Access OpenFaaS with an Istio Gateway

Tags: istio, istio-sidecar, openfaas, istio-gateway, istio-operator

I was trying to access OpenFaaS through istio in which I have included gateway and virtual service.

I need to create a separate endpoint for the OpenFaaS eg.: `"http://istio_ingress_Loadbalancer/openfaas"` - This should give me OpenFaaS UI.

Can anyone please help me, regarding I have hard time accessing this?
Below is the code I have written for gateway and virtual service.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: openfaas-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - port: 
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: openfaas-vs
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - openfaas-gateway.openfaas.svc.cluster.local
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /openfaas
    route:
    - destination:
        host: gateway.openfaas.svc.cluster.local
        port:
            number: 8080
```

Comment: Hello @Manjeet, welcome to StackOverflow! Could you explain what do you exactly mean by: "i am having hard time accessing this"? Do you have any error, responce code or other information about access trouble?

Comment: Hi @MikołajGłodziak thanks for reponding..if i say particularly for the above code in Virtual service, it is providing "404 page not found error" so is it possible to access openfaas UI with Istio gateway with separate endpoint url only? for eg:- http://istio_loadbalancer/openfaas if yes....how? I think i am missing something maybe..

Comment: I can see in your configuration that you named gateway as `openfass-gateway`.  But then in Virtual Service you are refering to the service `openfaas-gateway.openfaas.svc.cluster.local`. I don't think it would be right. Secondary, are your pods alive?  Maybe do you have gateway logs? [Here](https://docs.openfaas.com/deployment/troubleshooting/) is the doc, how to troubleshoot openfaas on kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

Add the namespace property in your Gateway yaml file.
Reference the gateway in your VirtualService yaml file with the following format :  <gateway-namespace>/<gateway-name>
https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#VirtualService